# How to get data from a cypress test into a JSON file?

Tags: json, cypress

I'm running a cypress test like this in the command line
        **npx cypress run --spec "src\test\cypress\profiling-tests\PerfExample.cypress.ts"**
is there away to get the data from this test into a json file? Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean the test results?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could use `cy.writeFile()`command. You could try below examples to write into a json file from the test:

The first example is witting the API response into a json file in fixture folder.

```
describe('API Testing and save as json data', () => {  

 var baseURL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon"

 beforeEach(() => {
      cy.request(baseURL+"/25").as('pikachu');
   });

 it('Write to a json file', () => {
        cy.get('@pikachu').then((response) => {
            var someArr = new Array();
             someArr = response;
            cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/testdata.txt', someArr);

        })
    });

});
```

Another example, if you got some array data in the test and want to write into a json file:

```
const someArr = [{name:"car", cost:"$1000", year:"2020"}];
cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/testdata.txt', someArr);
```